# view Inline Pages by typing page id in address bar in framework7

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

how to view Inline Pages by typing page id in address bar
example: index.html#register ?
i tried to make it but i failed

Answer (score 0):

You should use anchors

```
<ul>  
    <li><a href="#title1">title1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#title2">title2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#title3">title3</a></li>
</ul>      
<h2 id="title1">title1</h2>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<h2 id="title2">title2</h2>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<h2 id="title3">title3</h2>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
```